# SQL server stored procedure issue in via with c#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

```
comm = new SqlCommand("create procedure prabhat @para varchar(255) " +
                      "as " +
                      "insert into production.brands(brand_name) values(@para); " + 
                      "  go ", con);

comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

the above program is showing error as `incorrect syntax near go` 
i dont understand what might be causing it 
please help. 
i'm noob at this.

Comment: Just try to remove "go" string from command string

Comment: @picolino it worked thanks alot. 
but i dont understand why.

Comment: GO is a statement separator  that is understood by some tools. In particular Sql Server Management Studio, but you cannot use it in a query from code. If you need to execute more than one statement from code you use the ";" separator between commands

Comment: See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-ver15) for details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried below way which works as expected

```
        string connectionString = @"data source=WS-KIRON-01;initial catalog=MyCaseTestDb;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
        using (var _connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            _connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("create procedure prabhat @para varchar(255) as insert into LocalTestTable (name) values(@para)", _connection))
            {
                SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
                sqlDataReader.Close();
            }
            _connection.Close();

        }
```

> **Note:** [`GO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) generally used to distinguish separate batch operation on `SQL`. You  are getting error because you are asking `SQL server` for batch command but providing a single command that's why got
>   that error.